# Css grid Menu and NavBar

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I'm using `grid` display for the div `app_container`. Below is the structure of the component.

```
<div className="app_container">
  <Menu />   //Menu
  <NavBar />    //NavBar
  <div className="app-cont_routes"> //Routes
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/activity">
        <ActivityStack />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any here is the css:

```
.app_container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "navBar menu menu"
    "navBar routes routes"
    "navBar routes routes";
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
}

.menu {   /*Menu*/
  grid-area: menu;
}

.navBar_container {   /*NavBar*/
  grid-area: navBar;
}

.app-cont_routes {  /*Routes*/
  grid-area: routes;
}
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

But the result I'm getting is like:
[image]

The `Routes` is coming under the `NavBar`. 
Any help is greatly appreciated! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, at last! Here's the code I used:

```
.app_container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "nav-bar main-view";
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: main-view;
}

.navBar {
  grid-area: nav-bar;
}
.app-cont_routes {
  grid-area: main-view;
}
```